# Set browser resolution for CircleCI cimg/node:lts-browsers

Tags: node.js, browser, circleci, screen-resolution, docker-image

I'm using `cimg/node:lts-browsers` in CircleCI to do some UI automation tests with TestCafe. However, the default browser resolution is pretty low, how do I change the resolution to something like 1900x1080 or whatever the max is for the image?  I'm guessing you can set that with some env var like

```
      - image: cimg/node:lts-browsers
        environment:
          TERM: xterm
          SCREEN_WIDTH: 1900
          SCREEN_HEIGHT: 1080
```

but not sure what the actual env vars are.  thanks!